# How to save opened windows?

Tags: gnome, 12.10

My question should be pretty simple.

I have 12.10 with Gnome 3.6 as desktop, and I was wondering if it is possible to shutdown my computer and then start up again and all my windows and screens was restored from earlier, and just popped up again as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hibernating** your computer should help.

As Wikipedia page for [hibernation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28OS_feature%29) says:

> Hibernation in computing is powering down a computer while retaining
>   its state.
>
> Upon hibernation, the computer saves the contents of its random access
>   memory (RAM) to a hard disk or other non-volatile storage. Upon
>   resumption, the computer is exactly as it was upon entering
>   hibernation.

To enable hibernation:

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following command:

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

- Paste these in the file:

`[Enable Hibernate]

Identity=unix-user:*

Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate

ResultActive=yes`

- Save and close the file.
- Logout and login to see the hibernate option in the cog (Switch Off) menu.

Comment: but when i have to restart forced by an error in ubuntu, i can't use the hibernate solution. and that is my problem ?

Comment: In that case, you cannot do anything yet.